# unexpected Stripe webhook events received, which I can't find on Stripe dashboard

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I have setup a Webhook to my development environment. In addition to receiving the event notifications which I would expect, I receive additional notifications (with unique event ID) which do not make sense to me. When I try to look up those events on the Stripe dashboard I cannot find trace of them... Shouldn't all events be logged on the Dashboard?

Has anyone experienced this? I've popped a mail to the support but no answer yet.

**EDIT:**
I could find one of the "missing" events on the dashboard now. It was buried far down the event list, as it was apparently fired several hours ago for  the first time, but couldn't be handled at that time by my application.

Answer (score 2):

All events appear on the dashboard, listed at the time they are fired for the first time. So in case the application receiving the notification can't return a response 2xx for some reason, Stripe will try sending the notification again at a later time. Once the application server handles the event notification properly, the event will in all likelihood be logged by the application, and the timing might look confusing.